# How do I get rid of burning toothpaste in my throat?

Tags: personal-care, comfort

> **Problem**
>   I was brushing my teeth when a bit of toothpaste was on my lip and about to fall, I inhaled really hard and it when into my throat. My throat now burns and it feels like I have a sore throat from being sick.
>
> **Note**
>   It tastes like I have been inhaling matchstick smoke.

**Question**
What is the best way to get rid of the burning "sensation" and disgusting taste it has left behind in my mouth and throat?

Comment: Geez.. That sounds like some brutal toothpaste...

Comment: This exact thing jus happend to me. Literally one of the worst things I’ve had happen. Literally choked me out for 30 seconds finnaly was able to catch a breath and the pure burning throat followed after until I started to throw up.. I’m never brushing my teeth again. Big facts this tooth paste is out to get me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short of seeking medical attention, there's little you can do except drink water or gargle.
Presumably, as you took the time to write this question, you are in no immediate physical danger.

Any toothpaste that went beyond your epiglottis into your trachea rather than oesophagus will eventually be naturally flushed by your body. Excessive coughing is not really going to help, as the damage has been done by the toothpaste  ingredients & flavourings [the burning sensation], and it is unlikely you would have chosen this forum rather than a doctor were there actually significant solid matter still lodged there.

If you were actually sick, then a simple antacid [Rennies etc] will alleviate some of the symptoms.
Milk might also help.

Time will be the ultimate healer.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epiglottis for an overview of the terms used.

Comment: Thanks I already assumed I wasn't in immediate danger, just was wondering how to get rid of this crappy taste and burning. Guess I will have to wait it out thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Tetsujin's answer about it being on your epiglottis and trachea, on the way to your lungs, is probably right. If there's any in your esophagus, on the way to your stomach, you might be able to "wipe" it away by eating some bread. I would wash the break down with milk. Come to think of it, a bowl of cereal might help.

Comment: I ended up drinking carbonated water and eating bread after it settled down a bit (waited for it to stop burning and me to stop coughing).

Answer (score 0):

Toothpaste is not made for ingesting . Some of the substances in toothpaste are potentially toxic.

Sodium lauryl sulfate (SLS), a related detergent used in cosmetics, is a skin, eye and respiratory tract irritant and toxic to aquatic organisms.

The extensive use of triclosan in consumer products may contribute to antibiotic-resistant bacteria. Triclosan can pass through skin i and is suspected of interfering with hormone function (endocrine disruption).

Triclosan is used mainly in antiperspirants/deodorants, cleansers, and hand sanitizers as a preservative and an anti-bacterial agent. In addition to cosmetics, triclosan is also used as an antibacterial agent in laundry detergent, facial tissues, and antiseptics for wounds, as well as a preservative to resist bacteria, fungus, mildew and odors in other household products that are sometimes advertized as "anti-bacterial." These products include garbage bags, toys, linens, mattresses, toilet fixtures, clothing, furniture fabric, and paints. Triclosan also has medical applications.

Comment: yeah but wheres the amswer to my question? Thanks for the info though :)

Comment: You are right about "potentially toxic" but I checked this out (30 years ago but I doubt if it's changed much) and you would need to eat several tubes of toothpaste a day to be in danger. Bon Appetit!

Answer (score 0):

I just burned my throat with toothpaste.  AWFUL...!
and clearing my throat made it hurt more.

I went right to my medicine cabinet.

HALLS Honey Lemon menthol triple action lozenges.

The menthol cools and numbs the throat.

I always keep it on hand for a sore throat. It did the trick... I've found the HONEY-LEMON works better than the other flavors.  Keep it on hand always...!

Answer (score 0):

I just swallow some toothpaste. Drank a glass of cold milk it seemed to help it a lot.   It didn't cure. It kind of made it stop hurting. As much.